# Razer Headset mic not working

Tags: headset

Hey just got a Razer Krakken 7.1v2 usb headset.

The sound is working but the mic is not, i see the input level bar moving when i check the input settings and talk,but no sound is actually happening.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I have checked nothing is muted and increased the volume levels in alsamixer. The Razer is the only option in my input control so not sure why its not working.

Hoping someone can help me solve this!

Comment: *i see the input level bar moving* suggests it is working. How did you check it isn't? Please [edit] and provide details.